# How to tell a REST API which sub-resource to receive after a successful resource creation

Tags: rest, api, http

I have a REST API with a **purchase** resource, and each purchase has a **receipt** sub-resource that returns a pdf document with information about the purchase.

To create a purchase, the client does:

```
POST /purchase
```

And the client will get a `201 Created` HTTP response along a JSON representation of the purchase.

Most of the clients however want to receive the pdf receipt in:

```
GET /purchase/{id}/receipt
```

The client could do `POST /purchase`, receive the id of the new resource and call `GET /purchase/{id}/receipt` to download the receipt, but this will mean to make 2 requests instead of one.

Is there a RESTful way to indicate which sub-resource to receive after a successful resource creation?

Comment: how about POST will return JSON with the purchase and its receipt?

Comment: @AdamSiemion The receipt is a pdf document. Do you suggest I include it encoded in the json document?

Comment: Why are you trying to optimize this? What's wrong with an extra http call?

Comment: @RomanVottner this is the most RESTful way. Please can you write it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per request I convert my comment to an answer:

REST uses HTTP as its transport layer for messages exchanged between client and servers. Clients and servers are encouraged to adhere to the semantics of HTTP (and a couple of other constraints) in order to maintain interoperability and to decouple clients from server APIs.

HTTP offers the concept of content type negotiation where a client can ask the server for a certain representation format to receive a response in. The client expresses his intention with an [`Accept` header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.3) issued with the request. It can further give the server a list of supported representations by the client including and a weight parameter per media type which tells the server the preference order of each media type. If the client supports both PDF and JSON but prefers PDF over JSON it simply can send a request containing a header similar to

```
Accept: application/pdf;q=0.9,application/json;q=0.1
```

with the request.

If the server is able to convert the resource state into both of these representation formats it is encouraged to return a PDF representation as the client is prefering such format over the other. In case the server isn't able to generate a PDF representation for the resource state but is able to return a JSON one it simply can return JSON as it was told that the client still can handle it. If the server, however, can't create a representation the client can understand it has to return a [406 Not Acceptable](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.6) status code as response.